# How to know which program or service take long time at and after PC Starting?

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory-management, event-viewer

I want to identify which program consumes and takes computer resources on a Windows 7 during start up and after logging in, because after I log in my hard disk LED stays lit for almost 5 minutes.

I want to know which program "eats" my hard disk? And how do I make my PC faster?

Comment: Are you looking for something to log what happens from when you press the power button to when you log in, or when you log in to when you get to a usable desktop?

Comment: I'm looking for Log file to tell me which programs and services that start at log-in and take a big time to finish

Comment: good question. I'm having the same issue when windows os starting. Which solution helped you ?  Most programs like `Autorun` of Sysinternal list startup items but not the time it takes for each item to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many start-up managers capable of monitoring and controlling the boot process.

Some of them can report how long it takes for each service to start.

Check this list of freeware start-up managers:

http://www.snapfiles.com/Freeware/system/fwstartup.html

To be honest, I am personally have not used any of the listed programs, but
you can read each specific review and figure out which one is the best.

Comment: Thanks very much for all of you.
Mr.Roee Adler your answer was very helpful and may u consider the note that i put earlier. i'll choose Ocsid80's answer because it contain your program and many others.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should really give [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com) a try. Soluto is in beta and is free. It lists exactly how long each process and service take from your start-up, and recommends what you should do with each.

As full disclosure, I work at Soluto, but I'm not ashamed to offer our first feature as a solution to your problem (I'm a long time user here and have never offered Soluto in an answer). If you want to learn more, you can take a look at Robert Scoble's interview here: [Why can Soluto do what Microsoft can’t? They get rid of Windows frustrations](http://scobleizer.com/2010/05/24/why-can-soluto-do-what-microsoft-cant-they-get-rid-of-windows-frustrations-exclusive-first-look/).

If you give it a try - let us know how it goes :)

Comment: Might I recommend you update your page as to not show a blank page for users with JS disabled.

Comment: @Hello71: you mean that soluto.com is blank if you have JS disabled?

Comment: Well, the whole page above the fold is essentially blank, consisting of a logo, two blue gradients, and several presumably navigational icons.

Comment: Thanks I tried it.

It's very good but the program tell that boot time is about 2 minutes and finish his work too early while PC still work very hard and i almost can't run any program till HDD led stop flashing :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also use things like Process Monitor and Process Explorer from Sysinternals to track this like this down. Many times Antimalware products are the cause of these type things as they are updating and installing new defs and scanning everything that just loaded during the boot process.